# Bazel 0.29.1 LLVM-7.0 on Centos 7

Tags: centos, clang, llvm, bazel

So I have a docker with CentOS 7 which has installed bazel.
I've installed devtoolset-8, llvm-toolset-7.0 and centos-release-scl.
I've also installed bazel 0.29.1 and made.

```
export CC=clang
export CXX=clang++
```

I have an shell script which run basel. Befor bazel build command in top of the script I have

```
source /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/enable
```

which enables LLVM-7.0/Clang-7.0. But build failes with:

> /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/root/usr/bin/clang: error while loading
>   shared libraries: libLLVM-7.so: cannot open shared object file: No
>   such file or directory

But this lib exists! It's in */opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/root/usr/lib64/*

May someone pls help with this ?

Comment: same problem after comment 'source /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/enable' in bashrc

Answer (score 1):

Add below to .bash_profile or .bashrc:

```
source /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/enable
export CC=/opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/root/usr/bin/clang
export CXX=/opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/root/usr/bin/clang++
```

Run below as Root

```
echo /opt/rh/llvm-toolset-7.0/root/usr/lib64/ > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/llvm-toolset.conf
ldconfig
```